# Wowonder Configuration for Nginx Not Working

Tags: server, php, configuration, nginx

my wowonder PHP script website currently running on an apache server and it is working well. but I'm not happy with the speed it provides because my site is growing day by day and I need more speed and that is why I'm planning to migrate my website to an Nginx server and I tried myself many times to do that but there is not a single clear guide to do that.

I did try to do that by following guides about WordPress configuration but some of my website's pretty URLs throw 404 or 302 or just random errors.

developer of the script also provides rewrite rule nginx.conf file and I did try to use that but these rules are not working in /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf and /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

The installation guide is here. https://docs.wowonder.com/start.html

But I can't understand this guide I'm new to nginx. I spent almost 1 year trying to figure it out but had no luck because I don't know anything about nginx.

I did test my PHP working or by using info.php file. and looks like PHP is working I think I'm having a problem with my specific configuration or something else.

just some pretty urls not working config.php is fine. please if anyone can help me to build the configuration of Nginx for wowonder ill be really thankful.

I'm providing configuration samples here.

```
server {
listen 81;
listen [::]:81;
root /var/www/tmp;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @missing;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Wowonder URL rules which they provide.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rAJJyuqecCI8FOFbPWyjaMNC-TvVKrfZ08w4anf0NG4/edit?usp=sharing

Please have a look at my long-lasting problem and possibly help to fix it.

Edit:::

Thank all of you who paid attention to my problem but I found a solution. he helps me and he is writing a blog soon this will be complete and you can also benefit I'm providing a URL when it's complete you can also follow the solution.

https://dev.thewion.com/configure-wowonder-in-ubuntu-nginx-easy-and-fast-web-server

https://droidt99.com/read-blog/18503_how-to-install-wowonder-script-in-nginx-proxy.html

https://miui15.blogspot.com/2021/12/how-to-configure-wowonder-using-nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

Installation documentation is here:
https://docs.wowonder.com/

they have this text at the end
"Hmm, using Nginx? if your server is using Nginx, please follow the last steps below:

```
Open your server's root nginx.conf file, most of the time It's located it in: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
Open the home directory of the script, you should be able to find this file nginx.conf.
Open the located file, and copy its content to your root nginx.conf file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
If you find it something difficult to do, please contact your hosting provider, and they will do it for you easily.
```

"

I copied and pasted the content of the script's nginx into my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. However when validating the configuration. It did fail.

index.php loads fine, but internal pages like admincp.php doesnt load.

please help me to get this nginx config file correctly, where shall I insert the text from the script ? any specific section?

BTW I have haproxy--- nginx--- virtual hosts based on nginx.

Comment: This is a question, not an answer, to provide further details edit the original post.